# Wordpress Directory Permalink Structure

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields, permalinks

Looking to set up a Wordpress directory with hierarchical taxonomies.

Normal Wordpress "Pages" should have a simple `/%post_name%/` permalink. So "About" page would be site.com/about

I then have a Custom Post Type "Office". Office pages should follow this URL structure:

site.com/state/city/office-name/office-address

I then need each of these pages to be an archive of all Offices that they contain:

site.com/state

site.com/state/city

site.com/state/city/office-name

This seems like it would be a common site structure, but I have no idea how to get this working. I've tried a few combinations of Advanced Custom Fields, several permalink plugins, and taxonomies to no avail. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could pretty easily set this up using heirarchical taxonomies (basically categories for custom post types).

In your Custom Post Type, you can define [custom taxonomies](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Taxonomies), [Custom Post Type UI](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/) makes this even easier.

Just use a basic heirarchical taxonomy structure.

```
- "Washington"
---- "Vancouver"
-------- "Main Office"
-------- "Secondary Office"
---- "Tacoma"
-------- "Tacoma Main Office"
-------- "Tacoma Secondary Office"
- "California"
---- "Los Angeles"
-------- "LA Main Office"
```

etc, and just check the appropriate categories, and set the permalink to be the address.

Alternatively there are one hundred and one directory plugins (and themes) that may actually be better suited for your needs.